# Asynchronous python requests.post()

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-requests, python-asyncio

So the idea is to collect responses for 1 million queries and store them in a dictionary. I want it to be asynchronous because requests.post takes 1 second for each query and I want to keep the loop going while it's wait for response. After some research I have something like this.

```
async def get_response(id):
    query_json = id2json_dict[id]
    response = requests.post('some_url', json = query_json, verify=false)
    return eval(response.text)

async def main(id_list):
    for unique_id in id_list:
        id2response_dict[unique_id] = get_response(unique_id)
```

I know this is not asynchronous, how do I use "await" in it to make it truly asynchronous?

Comment: Use locust.io for that. It will be easier than building entire async/await or gevent based solution by your self.

Comment: The `requests` library does not support asyncio. For asynchronous http you probably want to check out [aiohttp](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: Future readers might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The `requests-async` pacakge provides asyncio support for `requests`... https://github.com/encode/requests-async

Either that or use `aiohttp`.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but this should work:

```
async def get_response(id):
    query_json = id2json_dict[id]
    # We need to_thread here because requests.post is synchronous.
    response = await asyncio.to_thread(
        requests.post, 
        'some_url', json = query_json, verify=false
    )
    return eval(response.text)


async def main(id_list):

    tasks = [
        get_response(unique_id) for unique_id in id_list
    ]

    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    id2response_dict = {
        unique_id: result 
        for (unique_id, result) in zip(id_list, results)
    }
```